# Any ways to allocate flattened array of structure as C in Common Lisp?

Tags: arrays, common-lisp

Are there any ways to allocate flattened array of structure (AOS) for efficiency in Common Lisp?

What I mean is the following C equivalent.

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  float y;
  double z;
} foo_t;

#define SIZE 1000000

void bar()
{
  foo_t *f = malloc( sizeof( foo_t ) * SIZE );
  do_something_with( f );
}
```

Usually in Common Lisp, array of pointers that refer structure objects are used to represent such a data structure.

```
(defstruct foo
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0.0 :type single-float)
  (z 0d0 :type double-float))

(let* ((size 1000000)
       (f (make-array size :element-type 'foo
                           :initial-contents (loop repeat size
                                                collect (make-foo)))))
  (do-something-with f))
```

When a structure has only a kind of type, simple arrays can be used to gain very efficient performance in imperative manner, although simple arrays accept only a kind of type as its element type.

```
; (defstruct vertex
;   (x 0d0 :type double-float)
;   (y 0d0 :type double-float)
;   (z 0d0 :type double-float))

(defun make-vertex-array (n)
  (make-array n :element-type 'double-float :initial-element 0d0))

(defmacro vertex-x (ary i)
  `(aref ,ary (+ (* ,i 3) 0)))

(defmacro vertex-y (ary i)
  `(aref ,ary (+ (* ,i 3) 1)))

(defmacro vertex-z (ary i)
  `(aref ,ary (+ (* ,i 3) 2)))

(let* ((size 1000000)
       (ary (make-vertex-array 100))
  (do-something-with ary))
```

I want to hear about something to do like this with structures with several kinds of element types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Common Lisp does not provide such a feature. I don't know of implementations which implement efficient arrays of structures, where the structures are allocated in the arrays. Implementations *might* implement efficient memory allocation for some structures, but usually not for vectors of structures.

It would provide a challenge to the garbage collector. Usually an object is garbage when there are no live references to it. If we would allow structures allocated inside arrays, the array would be garbage if there are no references to it AND no references into it (to any of the structures inside of the array).

There might be libraries which provide similar features ( http://cliki.net/data%20formats ).

There are usually FFI (foreign function interface) functionalities which can deal with arrays of records or one can build them using the FFI.

Comment: Thanks. As you say, I think about foreign memory allocation now because I've found its overhead to access elements of arrays of records is optimized to be fairly cheap.

Comment: About the garbage collector, I think arrays of records that I mean in this question are even easier to be garbage collected because they have no pointers to structures but have just unboxed primitive values such as fixnums or single/double floats.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to have a struct as an element type with efficient and neat access to the arguments of the structs? Why not just do it - whether or not this is 'efficient' depends on the implementation and you will not be able to influence it more that by the optimization options given by the software.

```
(defstruct foo 
  (x 0 :type fixnum)
  (y 0.0 :type single-float)
  (z 0d0 :type single-float))

(defun make-vertex-array (size)
  (make-array size :element-type 'foo :initial-contents (loop repeat size
                                                         collect (make-foo :x 0 :y 0.0 :z 0.0))))

(defparameter *test*
  (make-vertex-array 100))

(defmacro vertex-x (array i)
  `(foo-x (aref ,array ,i)))

(defmacro vertex-y (array i)
  `(foo-y (aref ,array ,i)))

(defmacro vertex-z (array i)
  `(foo-z (aref ,array ,i)))

(setf (vertex-x *test* 5) 4)

(setf (aref *test* 10) (make-foo :x 2 :y 0.0 :z 0.0))

(FORMAT T "~a~%" *test*)
>the array will be printed an you can see the changes  

(type-of *test*)
>(SIMPLE-VECTOR 100)

(type-of (make-array 100 :element-type 'integer))
>(SIMPLE-VECTOR 100)
```

According to [CLHS](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/typ_simple-vector.html)

> SIMPLE-VECTOR: The type of a vector that is not displaced to another array, has no
>   fill pointer, is not expressly adjustable and is able to hold elements
>   of any type is a subtype of type simple-vector.

[Further](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/syscla_vector.html#vector)

> Any one-dimensional array is a vector.

Now to your efficiency concerns. I did no benchmark so I'll have to stick with the manual. But it seems like SBCL should be optimizing.

[SBCL Manual on Efficiency](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Miscellaneous-Efficiency-Issues)

> ... the original CMUCL manual is still 95+% correct for the SBCL ...

[CMUCL on vectors](https://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/compiler-hint.html#toc194)

> Vectors (one dimensional arrays) are particularly useful, since in
>   addition to their obvious array-like applications, they are also well
>   suited to representing sequences. In comparison to a list
>   representation, vectors are faster to access and take up between two
>   and sixty-four times less space (depending on the element type.) As
>   with arbitrary arrays, the compiler needs to know that vectors are not
>   complex, so you should use simple-string in preference to string, etc.

Therefore some optimization is going on in the background. But whether or not this involves not using references and directly allocating the structs within the array is up to SBCL and you wont be able to influence that.

Comment: I want to use simple-array, which is more efficient than simple-vector.

Comment: @masayukitakagi: a simple-vector is just a simple-array with exactly one dimension.

Comment: @Svante Yes. Sorry for ambiguity. What I want to say was a "specialized" simple-array such as (SIMPLE-ARRAY DOUBLE-FLOAT *). And one dimensional equivalent is a specialized simple-vector.